# Can somebody explain how do I acces first name on my list? No matter which method do you use. Kivy, Python

Tags: python, indexing, kivy, kivy-language, writefile

I have an entry in which I typed 8 names: Nik, Tim, Nace, Peter, Tadej, Julij, Marjan, Slavko. Those names are saved in variable name.

I want to access and write in file only first or second name.

I tried normal indexing but it doesn't work and I get an error io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable.

```
def pressed(self, instance):
        name = self.name.text

        data_list = []
        data_list.append(name)


        def listToString(data_list):  

            str1 = " " 
  

            return (str1.join(data_list))
        
        
        
        print(listToString(data_list)) 

        
        f = open("print.txt","w", newline="")

        f.write(listToString(data_list))
        f = open("print.txt","r")

        with open("print.txt","w", encoding="UTF-8",newline="") as data_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(data_file)
            writer = csv.writer(data_file)
            writer.writerow(data_list[0])
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? What line?

Comment: `data_list = [n.trim() for n in self.name.text.split(",")]`  - beside that, you need to f.close() or better always use "with open(...) as f: ....".